# Adding a script to the edit & create admin pages for a custom post type

Tags: wordpress

I wish to add a admin script to certain admin pages.

However, the link: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts

only shows how to add scripts based on a hook. NOT the post type.

How can I add a script on the create and edit admin pages for a custom post type named product?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Look on your URL in admin menu for your custom post types. They all look like that:

```
/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=my_post_type
```

So you can easily make a condition to check on that `GET` parameter in `admin_enqueue_scripts`. If you need to target only certain pages, use the `$hook` parameter of `admin_enqueue_scripts`.

For pages that doesn't transport the post type, like the edit page, you can work with the classes on body tag. If you look into your source, you will noticed that `<body>` have the following class:

```
post-type-my_post_type
```

So in your JS, you can do:

```
if($('body').hasClass('post-type-my_post_type')) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: That's only good enough for some like adding a new post. The URL for editing a new post does not contain the post type. Only the post I'd.

Comment: Right. But in your javascript or css you can identify the post type you're working with based on the body classes. See updated answer.